# How to iterate a loop every n items

Tags: c#, loops

I have a list of items and I need to loop through it so that every n (eg. 3) items are first collected and then processed at once at the n'th item.

I'm doing the following:

```
List<MyObject> smallList = new List<MyObject>();

for (int i = 0; i < largeList.Count; i++)
{
    smallList.Add(largeList[i]);

    if (i % 3 == 0 || i >= largeList.Count - 3)
    {
        //Do somehting with those n items...
    }

    smallList.Clear();
 }
```

Is there a better way to do the above?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can also do this with LINQ:

```
var largeList = new List<int>(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 });
for (int i = 0; i < largeList.Count; i += 3)
{
    var items = largeList.Skip(i).Take(3).ToList();
    // do stuff with your 3 (or less items)
}
```

Comment: This might do a lot of full enumerations of the whole largeList.

Comment: You should start at `i=0`, otherwise you miss the first three.

Comment: @Toxantron indeed, fixed.

Comment: @Evk I'm pretty sure that `List` implements the `Skip` method in a constant time returning some lazy iterator.

Comment: @Kajacx yes you are right. Still good to avoid solutions that _might_ enumerate big lists many times under certain conditions. After all that is not much better than simple for loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with LINQ.

First, "attach" an index to each item:

```
var indexedItems = largeList.Select((item, index) => new {index, item});
```

Now group them by their index, while selecting the collection (`IEnumerable`) of items for each group member:

```
var groupedItems = indexedItems.GroupBy(indexedItem => indexedItem.index / 3,
                   indexedItem => indexedItem.item,
                   (key, items) => items);
```

Now process each group

```
foreach(var items in groupedItems) {
  // and optionally, .ToList() to have a List<T> instead of IEnumerable<T>
  var itemsList = items.ToList();
}
```

And altogether...:

```
var indexedItems = largeList.Select((item, index) => new {index, item});
var groupedItems = indexedItems.GroupBy(indexedItem => indexedItem.index / 3,
                   indexedItem => indexedItem.item,
                   (key, items) => items);

foreach(var items in groupedItems) {
  // Use the items...
}
```

Comment: Looks not much better than for loop :)

Comment: @Evk - I agree... I modified it to be more efficient, but I still don't see a reason not use a simple loop.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using nested loops. Not as pretty as LinQ, but certainly faster.

```
const int n = 3;
var small = new List();
for(var i=0; i<large.Count; i+=n)
{
    small.Clear();
    for(var j=i; j < n && j<large.Count; j++)
        small.Add(large[j]);
    // Do stuff with small
}
```

However quite similar to what you have now. I think it doesn't get much butter than what you have.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

```
var MyObjectList = new List<MyObject>();

MyObjectList.Where(a => MyObjectList.IndexOf(a) % 3 == 0).ToList().ForEach(a => 
{
        // do your things!
});
```